# Access attributes-array in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access an specific attribute in a json array. I've already looked [here](http://www.json.com/#object-with-nested-array-and-object) and it helped me for the general understanding but for my specific use case it does not work.

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "uuid": "3a8ed45f-28e7-4263-8437-d926c6a194f4",
    "number": "3310010",
    "shortname": "FUESTRUP",
    "longname": "FUESTRUP",
    "km": 102.177,
    "agency": "WSA RHEINE",
    "longitude": 7.680240800859249,
    "latitude": 52.04026675873374,
    "water": {
        "shortname": "EMS",
        "longname": "EMS"
    },
    "timeseries": [{
        "shortname": "W",
        "longname": "WASSERSTAND ROHDATEN",
        "unit": "cm",
        "equidistance": 15,
        "gaugeZero": {
            "unit": "m. ü. NN",
            "value": 35.69,
            "validFrom": "1952-02-01"
        }
    }]
}
```

Now I want to access the **value**-Property within the gaugeZero-Collection within the timeseries-array. I've already tried to do this by using:

> data.timeseries[0].longname.gaugeZero.value

but this does not work (it's undefinied).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: JSON is just a string are you converting your JSON to a javascript object first?

Answer (score 4):

`gaugeZero` is not a property of `longname`. You have to access it like this...

`data.timeseries[0].gauzeZero.value`

Assuming that data is the JavaScript object created from the JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I've made a typo - of course I know that `gaugeZero` is not a property of `longname`. Anyway...Thanks a lot :)  
Unfortunately now I have a different problem. I am working with Leaflet and the [**JsonLayer Plugin**](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-layerjson/), but by accessing `value` with your mentioned way, I get a error (the json file is coming from an url). I've created a [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFALm/) ( check Line 33/35, which make the trick) to show you the error. Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.timeseries[0].longname.gaugeZero.value
```

Won't ever work, as `longname` doesn't have a `gaugeZero` property. Just the same as trying `data.color` or `data.timeseries[0].animals` as examples.

You need to:

1. Get your JSON to an object.
2. Then having an object `data`:

   `data.timeseries[0].gaugeZero.value`

You can test it at your browser console or at ***Node repl*** and see the magic work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data.timeseries[0].gaugeZero.value` instead of

```
data.timeseries[0].longname.gaugeZero.value
```

.

Answer (score 0):

gaugeZero is not a property of longname

```
data['timeseries']["longname"]["gaugeZero"]["value"];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YP68N/

Comment: if there an alternative you can suggest?